# How to enable private data in fabric v1.3.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using fabric 1.3.0 in docker environment. I am getting error while trying to instantiate the chaincode with `--collections-config`. The setup is working fine if I remove the `--collections-config`

While executing :

```
peer chaincode instantiate -C org12 -n tranargy -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "OR('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" --collections-config /opt/gopath/src/tranargy/collections/collections_config.json
```

Getting following error :

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not
successful, error code 500, msg as V1_2 or later capability is not
enabled, private channel collections and data are not available
```

Can any one help in how to enable private data in fabric v1.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable the V1_3 capability when creating the channel configuration transaction.  See the required configuration in the [sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/first-network/configtx.yaml#L153-L156).  This is required so that all peers on a channel behave consistently, even if a rolling upgrade is in progress for the peers in the channel.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not using fabric 1.3.0 docker image
Even though it is present in your local, when you do compose up at that time it will download a new image of different version

Make sure

```
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.2.0               82c262e65984        3 months ago        159MB
```

compose file service `image: hyperledger/fabric-ca-peer:1.2.0`

Both versions  are same here i used 1.2.0
In your case 1.3.0

```
Make Sure:
Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
V1_3: true
```

See [configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/first-network/configtx.yaml#L153-L156)